# Process that Android will not be able to kill?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-broadcast

I've been thinking if there is a way to prevent an application process from being killed by Android if there is no visible UI component.

For example, there is a `Service` that performs some important work. Developer doesn't want to show any notification via `startForeground`, thus, the process will have **Service process** level according to http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html. So, if the system will be under heavy memory pressure, then there is a big chance android will stop the service.

I have one crazy idea in my mind. According to that page, the process will have **Foreground process** level if

> It hosts a `BroadcastReceiver` that's executing its `onReceive()` method.

What if developer starts a separate process with a service and a broadcast receiver which `onReceive()` never stops?

The code will look like this. For instance, developer has an `IntentService` and a `BroadcastReceiver` that work on a separate process:

```
<service
    android:name=".MyService"
    android:process=":myprocess">
</service>
<receiver
    android:name=".MyReceiver"
    android:process=":myprocess">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="MY_ACTION" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

The `BroadcastReceiver` looks this way:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // block main thread
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        // run this receiver again
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(MY_ACTION);
        context.sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

So, what happens here is, developer blocks `onReceive` method so that the process remains in foreground. The thread sleeps for 5 seconds because 10-second delay will cause ANR (according to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html). As I understand, there is no danger to block UI thread here because receiver works on a separate process. Then receiver sends a new broadcast to itself and this process never stops until developer disables the receiver via `PackageManager` at runtime.

Meanwhile developer interacts with his `IntentService` via `startService` calls. `IntentService` works on a background thread, so it will not be affected by that `MyReceiver`.

So, will that prevent a process and a service from being killed by Android if it's running low on memory? Of course I'm not going to implement that in my application but I'm very curious if that will work or not.

Comment: How about restarting your process whenever it got killed ?

Comment: Maybe developer doesn't want to stop the process? For instance they're using some socket connection

Answer (score 1):

Using `Thread.sleep()` in `onReceive()` will get you ANR too. `onReceive()` must return in 10 seconds else your process gets ANR and gets killed.

There are 2 ways to ensure your process does not get killed:

First is as you mentioned the `startForeground()`. This comes with a notification which you cannot hide unless you modify the AOSP.

The second method applies only if you are building the firmware. You can add a `android:persistant="true"` attribute in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

For regular apps the best approach is to use `START_STICKY` to reduce the odds of getting killed significantly and let Android restart your service automatically when it is killed. To ensure it gets started again you can use AlarmManager.

Comment: `onReceive` does return in 10 seconds so no ANR should be displayed, right? Thus, shouldn't be killed unless I'm missing something. I'm not building a firmware but I'll take a look at `android:persistant` anyway, thanks for the info.